# Proof of Higher Order Inverse Differential Operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having difficulty proving the following :

$\frac{1}{D^2+\alpha^2}\sin(\alpha x) = \frac{-x}{2\alpha}\cos(\alpha x)$

I know it won't use the transformation $P(D^2:\mapsto -\alpha^2)$, since it will put a zero in the denominator, and that it should involve the integral $\frac{1}{D}$, but that's as far as I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a differential operator $D$ in a denominator is somewhat irregular, I would say. Multiplying both sides with $D^2 + \alpha^2$ yields the equation
\begin{equation}
 (D^2 + \alpha^2)\left(\frac{-x}{2\alpha} \cos(\alpha x)\right) = \sin (\alpha x). \tag{1}
\end{equation}
You can easily prove the validity of $(1)$ by calculating the result of the application of the operator $(D^2 + \alpha^2)$ on the function $\frac{-x}{2\alpha} \cos(\alpha x)$.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I was just about to update my post saying I'd actually done just that. But now I'm curious, how would one have arrived at $\frac{-x}{2\alpha}\cos(\alpha x)$ in the first place?

Comment: That would be tantamount to solving the equation $y''(x) + \alpha^2 y(x) = \sin (\alpha x)$, for which I refer to the theory of solving linear nonhomogeneous second order differential equations with constant coefficients: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Nonhomogeneous_equation_with_constant_coefficients .

Comment: Right. I think my problem is that I was under the impression this property could be simplified and solved using other properties of Inverse D-Operators - as mentioned in my original post. So, unless I'm mistaken, this particular property has to be solved using the theory of linear non-homogeneous second order DE with constant coefficients and it is the result specifically that forms a property. I hope that makes sense ...

Comment: Actually, scratch that. I've found an explanation in the book [A Course in Ordinary Differential Equations](https://books.google.co.za/books?id=7j8W8Cw8iuMC&lpg=PA178&ots=wJBldWv0wL&dq=%22properties%20of%20the%20inverse%20differential%20operator%22%20differential&pg=PA190#v=onepage&q=%22properties%20of%20the%20inverse%20differential%20operator%22%20differential&f=false). It's Evaluation 5, toward the bottom of the linked page, if you're interested.
Thanks for your help!